# WPF TreeViewItem dyanmic context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm having some trouble with a databound TreeView in WPF, basically I want a context menu to be databound to an IEnumerable property on my TreeViewItem ViewModel, this is what I'm trying to do in the  of each TreeViewItem:

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
<Setter.Value>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenu}" />
</Setter.Value>
```

but it gives me an exception when loading the xaml saying it can't set ContextMenu on System.Object or something along those lines.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare it as resource in your style and then assign it to Value as StaticResource

```
<Style>
  <Style.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="contextmenustyle" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenu}" />
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextmenustyle}">
</Style>
```

Comment: ahh, excellent.. Any idea why it isn't possible how I was doing it? Seems like I'm not doing it wrong.. they should both produce the same result?

Comment: check this for details
http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/20/SharingAndSetterValue.aspx